# How to detect some significant transition in a sequence of numerical values

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I have a process that calculates a numerical value Y, as a function of an integer X (which is just the step in a selection process, so it increases from 1 to N by 1 unit at a time).
You can see below the plot of Y vs X.

[image]

Even without knowing what this is about (and it would be very hard to explain in just a few words), and even if the line were not coloured differently in different sections, it is arguable that the points where the colour changes are 'notable', i.e. they mark a consistent transition rather than an oscillation.

My goal is to identify these points when I don't know the 'colours' upfront, *most importantly without (too many) false positives*.

First attempt, as there seems to be a sharp change in 'slope' at those locations (assuming the concept of slope makes sense when X is discrete), I simply took the differences between each pair of contiguous Y's and plotted them.
This is what came up:

[image]

In a way this confirmed that those two points do have something special: the 'jump' between the two colours is one of the largest in the whole curve (or set of Y values).
This is in substantial agreement with the theory this comes from.

The problem, as you can see, is that there are many other places where large positive 'jumps' are observed, so it would be hard to choose which ones are 'notable' and which ones aren't.
In essence, the method of detection I chose seems to be too sensitive.

> **Can you suggest any method that somehow 'smooths' the parts of the curve that don't matter and only detects really significant transitions, in the sense I described above?**

I do appreciate that this sounds somewhat vague, not least because the definition of 'significance' of a transition would by itself provide a method to detect it.
Trouble is, I don't have such a precise definition. This is really completely empirical, and so must be my detection of the transition points. It might even require a different threshold for each separate case.
In essence I am trying to understand if the rather clear intuition of 'breaking points' one gets from the first plot can be translated into some rigorous procedure.
If it can't, and you think this is hopeless, fine: I just need to know if I should put any effort into it, and if you can suggest anything in that sense.

Thanks

---

**EDIT** adding the data, as suggested by Carl Christian

I could not find an easy way to drop the file somewhere, so here it is as csv plain text (note that there are strong oscillations at the end, which I had omitted from the pictures):

X,Y
0,358.767
1,358.696
2,358.635
3,358.613
4,358.578
5,358.612
6,358.637
7,358.647
8,358.629
9,358.638
10,358.578
11,358.51
12,358.438
13,358.355
14,358.269
15,358.299
16,358.354
17,358.323
18,358.332
19,358.347
20,358.338
21,358.335
22,358.343
23,358.335
24,358.334
25,358.323
26,358.344
27,358.377
28,358.392
29,358.421
30,358.436
31,358.456
32,358.458
33,358.48
34,358.493
35,358.505
36,358.505
37,358.511
38,358.535
39,358.531
40,358.553
41,358.579
42,358.544
43,358.563
44,358.592
45,358.581
46,358.581
47,358.575
48,358.584
49,358.581
50,358.587
51,358.602
52,358.622
53,358.608
54,358.63
55,358.617
56,358.611
57,358.632
58,358.628
59,358.635
60,358.669
61,358.714
62,358.725
63,358.723
64,358.752
65,358.733
66,358.754
67,358.741
68,358.749
69,358.74
70,358.755
71,358.779
72,358.777
73,358.793
74,358.782
75,358.799
76,358.765
77,358.731
78,358.744
79,358.787
80,358.775
81,358.757
82,358.75
83,358.736
84,358.742
85,358.749
86,358.745
87,358.717
88,358.706
89,358.726
90,358.719
91,358.635
92,358.564
93,358.582
94,358.57
95,358.597
96,358.584
97,358.565
98,358.561
99,358.549
100,358.553
101,358.571
102,358.539
103,358.507
104,358.484
105,358.46
106,358.464
107,358.417
108,358.353
109,358.326
110,358.246
111,358.197
112,358.162
113,358.108
114,358.053
115,358.026
116,357.983
117,357.972
118,357.957
119,357.917
120,357.874
121,357.822
122,357.794
123,357.745
124,357.687
125,357.655
126,357.607
127,357.554
128,357.489
129,357.469
130,357.439
131,357.392
132,357.311
133,357.26
134,357.195
135,357.105
136,357.027
137,356.961
138,356.939
139,356.893
140,356.884
141,356.841
142,356.833
143,356.813
144,356.779
145,356.732
146,356.715
147,356.666
148,356.646
149,356.59
150,356.579
151,356.586
152,356.579
153,356.525
154,356.521
155,356.486
156,356.438
157,356.353
158,356.332
159,356.352
160,356.269
161,356.275
162,356.28
163,356.264
164,356.227
165,356.201
166,356.18
167,356.176
168,356.176
169,356.12
170,356.048
171,355.984
172,355.92
173,355.907
174,355.837
175,355.755
176,355.649
177,355.565
178,355.442
179,355.38
180,355.292
181,355.223
182,355.175
183,355.135
184,355.075
185,354.978
186,354.905
187,354.856
188,354.831
189,354.759
190,354.662
191,354.601
192,354.623
193,354.518
194,354.488
195,354.43
196,354.421
197,354.436
198,354.432
199,354.354
200,354.335
201,354.299
202,354.289
203,354.265
204,354.194
205,354.127
206,354.063
207,354.075
208,354.011
209,353.968
210,353.934
211,353.895
212,353.841
213,353.836
214,353.789
215,353.734
216,353.722
217,353.665
218,353.571
219,353.553
220,353.496
221,353.454
222,353.42
223,353.332
224,353.237
225,353.125
226,353.059
227,352.978
228,352.889
229,352.797
230,352.767
231,352.651
232,352.601
233,352.496
234,352.434
235,352.351
236,352.304
237,352.24
238,352.218
239,352.202
240,352.163
241,352.136
242,352.082
243,352.046
244,351.989
245,351.94
246,351.883
247,351.857
248,351.829
249,351.817
250,351.793
251,351.743
252,351.681
253,351.584
254,351.55
255,351.515
256,351.421
257,351.349
258,351.299
259,351.252
260,351.17
261,351.003
262,350.921
263,350.861
264,350.791
265,350.747
266,350.715
267,350.67
268,350.627
269,350.603
270,350.597
271,350.517
272,350.437
273,350.347
274,350.267
275,350.223
276,350.114
277,350.056
278,349.962
279,349.879
280,349.813
281,349.73
282,349.707
283,349.65
284,349.584
285,349.558
286,349.424
287,349.356
288,349.311
289,349.239
290,349.194
291,349.199
292,349.184
293,348.993
294,348.841
295,348.685
296,348.645
297,348.566
298,348.51
299,348.427
300,348.342
301,348.276
302,348.168
303,348.057
304,347.908
305,347.812
306,347.727
307,347.684
308,347.646
309,347.562
310,347.473
311,347.411
312,347.328
313,347.253
314,347.155
315,347.01
316,346.859
317,346.751
318,346.663
319,346.614
320,346.545
321,346.42
322,346.279
323,346.228
324,346.15
325,345.994
326,345.833
327,345.679
328,345.543
329,345.404
330,345.241
331,345.113
332,344.974
333,344.853
334,344.721
335,344.555
336,344.446
337,344.347
338,344.245
339,344.135
340,344.033
341,343.928
342,343.841
343,343.784
344,343.718
345,343.642
346,343.561
347,343.468
348,343.349
349,343.244
350,343.155
351,343.064
352,342.957
353,342.817
354,342.747
355,342.667
356,342.616
357,342.548
358,342.471
359,342.395
360,342.297
361,342.219
362,342.104
363,341.968
364,341.855
365,341.743
366,341.606
367,341.472
368,341.347
369,341.241
370,341.113
371,340.88
372,340.694
373,340.539
374,340.41
375,340.217
376,340.091
377,339.913
378,339.781
379,339.641
380,339.492
381,339.331
382,339.199
383,339.015
384,338.801
385,338.609
386,338.53
387,338.408
388,338.361
389,338.262
390,338.142
391,338.066
392,337.916
393,337.79
394,337.633
395,337.485
396,337.357
397,337.192
398,337.058
399,336.951
400,336.822
401,336.704
402,336.551
403,336.364
404,336.194
405,336.053
406,335.953
407,335.842
408,335.723
409,335.603
410,335.511
411,335.382
412,335.158
413,334.975
414,334.844
415,334.691
416,334.536
417,334.349
418,334.175
419,334.045
420,333.926
421,333.795
422,333.653
423,333.518
424,333.347
425,333.21
426,333.07
427,332.87
428,332.661
429,332.509
430,332.369
431,332.219
432,332.001
433,331.796
434,331.543
435,331.258
436,330.971
437,330.806
438,330.533
439,330.313
440,330.104
441,329.941
442,329.763
443,329.561
444,329.366
445,329.227
446,329.066
447,328.84
448,328.63
449,328.436
450,328.242
451,328.013
452,327.734
453,327.52
454,327.301
455,327.133
456,326.917
457,326.695
458,326.577
459,326.436
460,326.234
461,326.068
462,325.878
463,325.641
464,325.448
465,325.214
466,324.891
467,324.688
468,324.497
469,324.275
470,324.062
471,323.833
472,323.626
473,323.441
474,323.239
475,323.032
476,322.802
477,322.565
478,322.304
479,322.014
480,321.707
481,321.392
482,321.129
483,320.843
484,320.609
485,320.33
486,320.033
487,319.691
488,319.373
489,319.01
490,318.972
491,318.965
492,318.96
493,318.966
494,319.008
495,319.05
496,319.041
497,319.021
498,318.977
499,319.004
500,319.056
501,319.08
502,319.08
503,319.11
504,319.088
505,319.125
506,319.152
507,319.132
508,319.134
509,319.202
510,319.163
511,319.182
512,319.205
513,319.253
514,319.279
515,319.344
516,319.391
517,319.345
518,319.357
519,319.391
520,319.358
521,319.368
522,319.4
523,319.348
524,319.358
525,319.371
526,319.352
527,319.318
528,319.252
529,319.208
530,319.201
531,319.205
532,319.23
533,319.255
534,319.287
535,319.269
536,319.279
537,319.296
538,319.351
539,319.395
540,319.466
541,319.454
542,319.47
543,319.504
544,319.594
545,319.619
546,319.661
547,319.713
548,319.766
549,319.84
550,319.97
551,319.932
552,319.928
553,319.933
554,320
555,320.042
556,320.083
557,320.144
558,320.209
559,320.261
560,320.28
561,320.247
562,320.185
563,320.159
564,319.997
565,320.108
566,320.158
567,320.233
568,320.244
569,320.294
570,320.367
571,320.465
572,320.583
573,320.496
574,320.489
575,320.485
576,320.428
577,320.433
578,320.454
579,320.552
580,320.565
581,320.588
582,320.665
583,320.666
584,320.689
585,320.722
586,320.737
587,320.809
588,320.899
589,321.01
590,321.043
591,321.047
592,321.084
593,321.163
594,321.237
595,321.266
596,321.296
597,321.357
598,321.423
599,321.392
600,321.384
601,321.37
602,321.377
603,321.332
604,321.318
605,321.318
606,321.294
607,321.249
608,321.264
609,321.287
610,321.275
611,321.269
612,321.307
613,321.223
614,321.297
615,321.302
616,321.296
617,321.29
618,321.33
619,321.387
620,321.348
621,321.394
622,321.426
623,321.403
624,321.405
625,321.402
626,321.431
627,321.46
628,321.453
629,321.471
630,321.448
631,321.551
632,321.579
633,321.664
634,321.686
635,321.724
636,321.771
637,321.814
638,321.862
639,321.913
640,321.93
641,321.976
642,321.996
643,322.028
644,322.072
645,322.091
646,322.112
647,322.125
648,322.148
649,322.18
650,322.223
651,322.28
652,322.317
653,322.36
654,322.376
655,322.401
656,322.411
657,322.496
658,322.596
659,322.634
660,322.648
661,322.693
662,322.751
663,322.769
664,322.809
665,322.867
666,322.924
667,323.019
668,322.987
669,322.972
670,322.98
671,322.969
672,322.922
673,322.914
674,322.976
675,323.068
676,323.127
677,323.158
678,323.177
679,323.209
680,323.243
681,323.339
682,323.348
683,323.439
684,323.514
685,323.483
686,323.413
687,323.354
688,323.353
689,323.365
690,323.467
691,323.48
692,323.403
693,323.413
694,323.338
695,323.27
696,323.347
697,323.346
698,323.447
699,323.492
700,323.578
701,323.61
702,323.653
703,323.724
704,323.788
705,323.808
706,323.862
707,323.969
708,324.003
709,324.001
710,324.049
711,324.146
712,324.143
713,324.077
714,324.153
715,324.215
716,324.287
717,324.375
718,324.479
719,324.513
720,324.547
721,324.478
722,324.392
723,324.425
724,324.438
725,324.452
726,324.513
727,324.586
728,324.682
729,324.708
730,324.768
731,324.864
732,324.83
733,324.802
734,324.842
735,324.897
736,324.895
737,324.923
738,325.047
739,325.155
740,325.295
741,325.441
742,325.417
743,325.388
744,325.427
745,325.424
746,325.452
747,325.481
748,325.537
749,325.611
750,325.639
751,325.688
752,325.731
753,325.825
754,325.875
755,325.921
756,325.958
757,326.063
758,325.996
759,326.046
760,326.082
761,326.093
762,326.157
763,326.231
764,326.191
765,326.249
766,326.297
767,326.372
768,326.432
769,326.458
770,326.483
771,326.513
772,326.536
773,326.439
774,326.355
775,326.315
776,326.258
777,326.228
778,326.158
779,326.124
780,326.078
781,326.072
782,326.01
783,325.959
784,325.931
785,325.808
786,325.76
787,325.705
788,325.749
789,325.684
790,325.623
791,325.634
792,325.644
793,325.635
794,325.7
795,325.763
796,325.754
797,325.783
798,325.797
799,325.869
800,325.846
801,325.825
802,325.859
803,325.903
804,325.912
805,325.974
806,326.003
807,326.004
808,326.046
809,326.11
810,326.147
811,326.213
812,326.269
813,326.35
814,326.356
815,326.413
816,326.343
817,326.325
818,326.372
819,326.442
820,326.485
821,326.583
822,326.593
823,326.57
824,326.567
825,326.569
826,326.546
827,326.577
828,326.628
829,326.657
830,326.663
831,326.655
832,326.751
833,326.757
834,326.764
835,326.768
836,326.912
837,326.954
838,327.018
839,327.104
840,327.125
841,327.112
842,327.139
843,327.219
844,327.316
845,327.417
846,327.478
847,327.494
848,327.458
849,327.386
850,327.45
851,327.397
852,327.398
853,327.452
854,327.436
855,327.392
856,327.428
857,327.463
858,327.472
859,327.435
860,327.415
861,327.348
862,327.26
863,327.183
864,327.104
865,327.007
866,326.921
867,326.864
868,326.832
869,326.87
870,326.894
871,326.887
872,326.942
873,326.905
874,326.855
875,326.874
876,326.832
877,326.866
878,326.947
879,326.972
880,326.956
881,326.985
882,327.061
883,327.154
884,327.197
885,327.186
886,327.272
887,327.371
888,327.376
889,327.388
890,327.411
891,327.412
892,327.491
893,327.504
894,327.492
895,327.439
896,327.34
897,327.337
898,327.326
899,327.32
900,327.337
901,327.324
902,327.322
903,327.331
904,327.294
905,327.252
906,327.228
907,327.15
908,327.078
909,327.1
910,327.109
911,327.055
912,327.091
913,327.148
914,327.095
915,327.065
916,327.036
917,327.019
918,327.086
919,327.154
920,327.19
921,327.143
922,327.103
923,327.155
924,327.222
925,327.282
926,327.327
927,327.301
928,327.368
929,327.309
930,327.293
931,327.273
932,327.293
933,327.315
934,327.31
935,327.277
936,327.293
937,327.235
938,327.137
939,327.171
940,327.078
941,327.118
942,327.19
943,327.253
944,327.3
945,327.257
946,327.311
947,327.346
948,327.432
949,327.545
950,327.622
951,327.801
952,327.84
953,327.87
954,327.898
955,327.998
956,327.971
957,327.964
958,327.984
959,328.021
960,328.084
961,328.108
962,328.152
963,328.218
964,328.277
965,328.323
966,328.266
967,328.285
968,328.342
969,328.358
970,328.535
971,328.499
972,328.549
973,328.618
974,328.605
975,328.63
976,328.66
977,328.677
978,328.666
979,328.631
980,328.599
981,328.619
982,328.668
983,328.651
984,328.724
985,328.718
986,328.747
987,328.707
988,328.79
989,328.778
990,328.69
991,328.776
992,328.83
993,328.869
994,328.85
995,328.951
996,329.014
997,329.019
998,329.062
999,329.018
1000,328.964
1001,329.074
1002,328.957
1003,328.953
1004,328.995
1005,329.01
1006,329.032
1007,329.044
1008,329.022
1009,329.105
1010,328.848
1011,328.806
1012,328.808
1013,328.786
1014,328.786
1015,328.8
1016,328.807
1017,328.839
1018,328.764
1019,328.755
1020,328.742
1021,328.65
1022,328.582
1023,328.388
1024,328.387
1025,328.37
1026,328.281
1027,328.203
1028,328.127
1029,328.081
1030,327.923
1031,327.837
1032,327.776
1033,327.689
1034,327.68
1035,327.697
1036,327.713
1037,327.545
1038,327.588
1039,327.612
1040,327.722
1041,327.74
1042,327.812
1043,327.757
1044,327.808
1045,327.843
1046,327.716
1047,327.582
1048,327.513
1049,327.479
1050,327.433
1051,327.336
1052,327.244
1053,327.194
1054,327.141
1055,327.129
1056,327.117
1057,327.146
1058,327.12
1059,327.215
1060,327.165
1061,327.146
1062,327.14
1063,327.13
1064,327.151
1065,327.142
1066,327.098
1067,327.116
1068,327.143
1069,327.161
1070,327.244
1071,327.298
1072,327.342
1073,327.356
1074,327.368
1075,327.335
1076,327.255
1077,327.154
1078,327.113
1079,327.065
1080,326.99
1081,327.005
1082,326.964
1083,326.877
1084,326.896
1085,326.951
1086,326.959
1087,326.975
1088,327.033
1089,327.042
1090,326.919
1091,326.841
1092,326.81
1093,326.642
1094,326.533
1095,326.474
1096,326.419
1097,326.37
1098,326.357
1099,326.203
1100,326.133
1101,326.11
1102,326.042
1103,326.022
1104,325.943
1105,325.859
1106,325.803
1107,325.725
1108,325.626
1109,325.684
1110,325.646
1111,325.628
1112,325.594
1113,325.584
1114,325.554
1115,325.486
1116,325.429
1117,325.285
1118,325.294
1119,325.274
1120,325.269
1121,325.212
1122,325.163
1123,325.082
1124,325.123
1125,325.128
1126,325.164
1127,325.079
1128,324.972
1129,324.93
1130,324.826
1131,324.736
1132,324.646
1133,324.335
1134,324.175
1135,324.024
1136,323.887
1137,323.715
1138,323.672
1139,323.641
1140,323.541
1141,323.413
1142,323.32
1143,323.172
1144,323.077
1145,323.004
1146,323.016
1147,322.916
1148,322.938
1149,322.951
1150,322.833
1151,322.786
1152,322.726
1153,322.655
1154,322.591
1155,322.436
1156,322.351
1157,322.366
1158,322.2
1159,322.022
1160,321.91
1161,321.804
1162,321.611
1163,321.491
1164,321.449
1165,321.38
1166,321.378
1167,321.403
1168,321.281
1169,321.181
1170,321.173
1171,321.098
1172,321.036
1173,321.015
1174,321.033
1175,321.066
1176,321.098
1177,321.132
1178,321.089
1179,320.991
1180,320.896
1181,320.738
1182,320.695
1183,320.694
1184,320.643
1185,320.573
1186,320.504
1187,320.379
1188,320.239
1189,320.229
1190,320.157
1191,320.091
1192,320.075
1193,319.993
1194,319.772
1195,319.726
1196,319.736
1197,319.691
1198,319.59
1199,319.467
1200,319.332
1201,319.334
1202,319.176
1203,319.021
1204,318.905
1205,318.778
1206,318.649
1207,318.466
1208,318.309
1209,318.143
1210,318.126
1211,317.916
1212,317.705
1213,317.626
1214,317.586
1215,317.459
1216,317.446
1217,317.459
1218,317.433
1219,317.409
1220,317.442
1221,317.466
1222,317.399
1223,317.415
1224,317.458
1225,317.542
1226,317.489
1227,317.413
1228,317.344
1229,317.29
1230,317.255
1231,317.223
1232,317.204
1233,316.96
1234,316.603
1235,316.612
1236,316.411
1237,316.286
1238,316.161
1239,316.057
1240,315.968
1241,315.938
1242,315.847
1243,315.639
1244,315.679
1245,315.563
1246,315.52
1247,315.53
1248,315.375
1249,315.323
1250,315.057
1251,314.845
1252,314.679
1253,314.49
1254,314.271
1255,314.011
1256,313.779
1257,313.479
1258,313.292
1259,313.061
1260,312.883
1261,312.686
1262,312.549
1263,312.333
1264,312.073
1265,311.825
1266,311.588
1267,311.317
1268,310.989
1269,310.608
1270,310.515
1271,310.357
1272,310.215
1273,309.851
1274,309.566
1275,309.452
1276,309.156
1277,308.882
1278,308.74
1279,308.584
1280,308.416
1281,308.367
1282,308.41
1283,308.223
1284,308.01
1285,307.85
1286,307.571
1287,307.222
1288,306.953
1289,306.791
1290,306.637
1291,306.501
1292,306.292
1293,305.961
1294,305.599
1295,305.367
1296,305.17
1297,304.998
1298,304.875
1299,304.709
1300,304.575
1301,304.489
1302,304.273
1303,304.054
1304,303.9
1305,303.773
1306,303.586
1307,303.282
1308,303.133
1309,302.927
1310,302.739
1311,302.558
1312,302.349
1313,302.061
1314,301.722
1315,301.355
1316,300.988
1317,300.78
1318,300.554
1319,300.376
1320,299.987
1321,299.615
1322,299.287
1323,299.091
1324,298.841
1325,298.703
1326,298.572
1327,298.526
1328,298.307
1329,298.214
1330,297.935
1331,297.969
1332,297.66
1333,297.558
1334,297.398
1335,297.131
1336,296.937
1337,296.728
1338,296.533
1339,296.175
1340,295.839
1341,295.672
1342,295.486
1343,295.105
1344,294.691
1345,294.312
1346,293.959
1347,293.508
1348,293.111
1349,292.737
1350,292.348
1351,292.057
1352,291.667
1353,291.469
1354,291.154
1355,290.758
1356,290.564
1357,290.329
1358,290.115
1359,289.697
1360,289.399
1361,288.999
1362,288.535
1363,288.271
1364,287.755
1365,287.318
1366,286.833
1367,286.329
1368,286.016
1369,285.678
1370,284.964
1371,284.455
1372,283.898
1373,283.536
1374,282.907
1375,282.452
1376,281.999
1377,281.29
1378,280.781
1379,280.102
1380,279.673
1381,279.13
1382,278.491
1383,277.713
1384,277.086
1385,276.317
1386,275.537
1387,275.006
1388,274.427
1389,273.879
1390,273.115
1391,272.4
1392,271.758
1393,271.28
1394,270.752
1395,270.343
1396,269.847
1397,269.812
1398,269.578
1399,269.298
1400,268.812
1401,268.195
1402,267.497
1403,266.978
1404,266.389
1405,265.86
1406,265.307
1407,264.792
1408,264.278
1409,263.642
1410,262.924
1411,262.162
1412,261.625
1413,261.068
1414,260.327
1415,259.519
1416,258.794
1417,257.973
1418,257.18
1419,256.507
1420,255.878
1421,255.239
1422,254.59
1423,253.912
1424,253.214
1425,252.43
1426,251.536
1427,250.794
1428,249.968
1429,249.288
1430,248.497
1431,247.708
1432,246.898
1433,246.105
1434,245.29
1435,244.45
1436,243.444
1437,242.686
1438,241.831
1439,241.075
1440,240.184
1441,239.149
1442,238.04
1443,237.491
1444,237.573
1445,237.689
1446,237.586
1447,237.655
1448,237.727
1449,237.859
1450,237.973
1451,238.085
1452,238.138
1453,238.187
1454,238.183
1455,238.221
1456,238.29
1457,238.478
1458,238.508
1459,238.514
1460,238.573
1461,238.803
1462,238.846
1463,238.392
1464,238.439
1465,238.568
1466,238.659
1467,238.654
1468,238.848
1469,239.137
1470,238.635
1471,238.521
1472,238.456
1473,238.374
1474,238.56
1475,238.352
1476,238.102
1477,238.074
1478,238.074
1479,238.046
1480,238.147
1481,238.398
1482,238.562
1483,238.669
1484,239.023
1485,239.278
1486,239.446
1487,239.846
1488,239.658
1489,239.497
1490,239.465
1491,239.482
1492,239.514
1493,239.603
1494,239.687
1495,239.861
1496,239.96
1497,240.187
1498,240.408
1499,240.703
1500,241.083
1501,241.346
1502,241.69
1503,242.108
1504,242.417
1505,242.41
1506,242.453
1507,242.68
1508,242.816
1509,243.054
1510,243.309
1511,243.576
1512,243.786
1513,243.954
1514,244.233
1515,244.394
1516,244.586
1517,244.731
1518,244.812
1519,244.733
1520,245.02
1521,245.267
1522,245.453
1523,245.622
1524,245.897
1525,246.178
1526,246.244
1527,246.363
1528,246.446
1529,246.83
1530,247.213
1531,247.588
1532,247.731
1533,247.72
1534,247.944
1535,248.049
1536,248.325
1537,248.652
1538,248.85
1539,249.054
1540,249.527
1541,249.897
1542,250.237
1543,250.528
1544,250.693
1545,250.886
1546,251.038
1547,251.261
1548,251.719
1549,252.266
1550,252.769
1551,253.248
1552,253.765
1553,254.282
1554,254.847
1555,255.112
1556,254.985
1557,254.734
1558,254.741
1559,254.537
1560,254.208
1561,254.371
1562,254.55
1563,254.8
1564,254.86
1565,255.153
1566,255.505
1567,255.804
1568,256.152
1569,256.608
1570,256.85
1571,256.956
1572,257.132
1573,257.241
1574,257.543
1575,257.54
1576,257.917
1577,258.214
1578,258.448
1579,258.662
1580,258.865
1581,259.099
1582,259.21
1583,259.179
1584,259.26
1585,259.504
1586,259.609
1587,259.59
1588,259.594
1589,259.594
1590,259.726
1591,260.129
1592,260.528
1593,260.841
1594,260.998
1595,261.523
1596,262.099
1597,262.475
1598,262.822
1599,263.38
1600,263.97
1601,264.324
1602,264.704
1603,265.128
1604,265.421
1605,265.997
1606,266.429
1607,266.143
1608,266.22
1609,266.539
1610,266.79
1611,267.017
1612,267.11
1613,267.248
1614,267.571
1615,268.015
1616,268.337
1617,268.614
1618,268.773
1619,269.275
1620,269.444
1621,269.58
1622,269.908
1623,270.465
1624,270.839
1625,271.058
1626,271.396
1627,271.669
1628,271.496
1629,272.062
1630,272.657
1631,273.237
1632,273.799
1633,274.421
1634,274.044
1635,273.528
1636,273.696
1637,274.052
1638,274.035
1639,274.131
1640,273.982
1641,274.11
1642,273.828
1643,273.976
1644,273.82
1645,273.825
1646,274.004
1647,274.352
1648,274.593
1649,274.816
1650,273.86
1651,273.991
1652,274.421
1653,274.736
1654,274.968
1655,275.165
1656,275.15
1657,275.675
1658,275.79
1659,276.097
1660,276.144
1661,276.404
1662,276.395
1663,276
1664,275.406
1665,276.068
1666,276.697
1667,277.27
1668,275.805
1669,274.568
1670,275.225
1671,275.964
1672,276.284
1673,277.198
1674,277.173
1675,277.297
1676,277.393
1677,277.953
1678,278.238
1679,278.512
1680,278.791
1681,279.234
1682,279.501
1683,279.393
1684,279.074
1685,278.9
1686,278.211
1687,277.864
1688,276.733
1689,276.782
1690,276.763
1691,276.214
1692,276.888
1693,276.387
1694,276.332
1695,277.104
1696,276.043
1697,274.931
1698,275.501
1699,276.399
1700,277.439
1701,278.074
1702,278.85
1703,279.503
1704,280.012
1705,280.496
1706,280.839
1707,280.101
1708,279.379
1709,279.856
1710,280.264
1711,280.168
1712,280.224
1713,279.659
1714,279.615
1715,279.703
1716,280.273
1717,280.876
1718,281.855
1719,282.276
1720,282.36
1721,282.73
1722,282.179
1723,282.184
1724,282.847
1725,283.303
1726,283.254
1727,281.916
1728,280.301
1729,280.335
1730,281.281
1731,281.752
1732,283.086
1733,283.253
1734,284.438
1735,285.439
1736,286.256
1737,286.826
1738,286.795
1739,285.958
1740,284.79
1741,282.104
1742,280.302
1743,278.779
1744,278.322
1745,277.436
1746,277.367
1747,276.535
1748,275.642
1749,274.319
1750,271.967
1751,271.694
1752,269.462
1753,268.572
1754,268.384
1755,267.168
1756,266.175
1757,264.548
1758,261.394
1759,257.287
1760,254.72
1761,251.129
1762,246.098
1763,240.937
1764,234.681
1765,224.616
1766,216.816
1767,208.23
1768,196.458
1769,176.151
1770,173.47
1771,170.219
1772,165.794
1773,160.027
1774,153.809
1775,146.222
1776,142.906
1777,135.087
1778,134.305
1779,130.126
1780,128.917
1781,123.605
1782,127.474
1783,130.478
1784,132.22
1785,133.573
1786,131.303
1787,131.538
1788,124.888
1789,122.835
1790,101.98
1791,87.238
1792,0
1793,0
1794,0

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Would you add a link to the data in an easily accessible format, say, 2 columns that are comma separated or otherwise MATLAB compatible. My immediate suggestion is to replace the data with a moving average and then look for spikes in the second derivative of the moving average.

Comment: Thanks! OK sure, I will see how I can share them.

Comment: My suggestion does not appear to bear fruit. I tried to add random noise to the function $x \rightarrow |x|$ and I could not recover the point of bending. This paper sounds much more promising https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508586 but it is late in my timezone so I have even browsed it.